# ActiveMQ define message consumer when more than one consumer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using `ActiveMQ` and I have a `Queue` with one **consumer** in the production environment.

For integration testing, I created a small application that using JNDI connects to the ActiveMQ Broker and consumes from the same queue. What I want is to separate test messages and only consume them.

Is there a way to define who should be the consumer of a message? Or any other solution that could help me to achieve this?

I know one solution could be to use **Mirrored Queues**, but I don't want to modify my code for testing purposes.

Comment: you can create a v-host and create the queues there, and point both producer and consumer to that v-host... will that work?

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: a single mq server can contain multiple hosts, by  default it uses the root host `/`. but we can add more v-hosts.. if you create a new v-host, inside that we can define queue, bindings, exchanges etc.. sort of like two VMs running in same system. each v-hosts are completely isolated. mq clients have option to specify which v-host to connect to. I'm saying all these with my experience with RabbitMQ.. you can check this https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/user-manual.html#Virtual_Hosts

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need test messages in production? (that can easily become a ticking bomb). If you're brave enough (and potentially reckless :D), you can use a [message selector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html), so the production consumers do not consume message tagged as test, and your test consumer only consumes test messages.

Bear in mind that some JMS brokers might slow down considerably when you use this feature.

Comment: I will nor run the test against production, sorry I didn't explain it well, It will be ran against test environments.

Comment: Have you considered having a different broker instance for your test environment?

Comment: The broker is not part of my system.